# Force UEFI installation?

Tags: uefi, bios, reinstall

I'm trying a fix or more preferably a reinstall on the previous Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS I had installed as I had lots of issues with and instead of going the hard way, I simply went for a reinstall. The question is, will it harm my HDD or performance in the long run if I force installation, as in the old one won't be deleted and somehow stay there, hidden? Please note that I do not have any important data on the previous installation, so I don't mind losing it at all.[image: Here's the photo.]

Comment: As far as I know reinstalling doesn't require you to force anything. Whats the issue?

Comment: Wow, thats new. It's either because your GPT disk contains a BIOS Boot partition or its just telling you the disk is DOS partitioned? although that'd be weird. I doubt it'd hurt anyway.

Comment: I've added a picture of the text window. During installation, it recognized another operating system, which is my faulty previous 16.04.3 LTS, but I get this. Again, I don't mind erasing all the data on that one if there's an option.

Comment: I think it contains a BIOS Boot Partition. I used Rufus to create an USB Stick for installation with the help of an Ubuntu installation tutorial, although, I thought I would be prompted something else regarding my previous Ubuntu.

Comment: After proceeding to the next step, it showed options for reinstalling, installing alongside my previous one or just wiping out the entire disk of data and continue, although still not option for manually choosing my partitions even though I followed the tutorial step by step, he chose Erase Disk as well, and he had a little option there where he could partition his whole disk or  use it all, but I didn't get any, it went straight for my Location, language, keyboard and such. No huge thing, I can still use GParted after.

Comment: I wish I could find it in the source code.

Comment: How many physical hard drives do you have installed in the computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If hard disk disk has partitioning scheme as gpt then we can do UEFI installation of any os

And if it is having msdos or mbr then we can do installation in legacy.

Now legacy (bios) or UEFI are the low level softwares and are firmware types which boots before your os.

So you got the pair 
Gpt -> uefi
Msdos or mbr -> bios or legacy.

It seems that your hdd is in second case ie
Msdos and legacy firmware.

Every os has 2 copies while booting in a bootable disk.These are one for legacy and other for uefi.
So you have selected uefi copy of ubuntu and installing on legacy firmware hence it is forcing installation in uefi.

It will not harm your other system most probably .just it will not boot normally 
You have to go into bios for staring that os.

So i think 
You should reinstall it as
Select legacy copy of the os (option which in other than uefi disk )which is in bios ie 
When you join your disk to pc
Enter into bios for boot menu
And in that you will get those options
Select that and install...

Hope it could help you 
Forgive it something went wrong..